# C on Linux: Running 25 parallel processes is significantly quicker than running 24

Tags: linux, process, c

My C-program uses fork() to create new processes and I measure the time it takes for each one of these processes to do its work. In fact, I let them do the work 10000 times and measure that time.

The measurements are done by gettimeofday(...) and the results are printed after each process if finished.

To the point: By running 24 parallel processes these times are centered around 180 000 usec. But when I increase to 25 processes the time drops down and centers around 100 000 usec. Is this something Linux specific? That by creating more processes I am given more resources from the OS?

Or is it completely impossible and I am measuring the time wrong? 
It should be noted that the measurements are increasing for 1->24 processes and drops on the 25th.

Comment: You would need to profile your whole process and server usage to clarify the cause.  Without seeing the code and spending a few hours on it, it's impossible to guess what would cause it.  My first impression though is either cache or shared memory related, or your process inefficiently waits for something and increasing the machine's load reduces that waste.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thank you. I seemed to have traced to issue to other processes on the machine. Others were SSH:ed onto the same system and ran processes simultaneously.